# Constraint to disallow overlapping dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, constraints

I'm trying to create a table in postgres of product promotions, this is a simplified example:

```
create table promotions
(
    product_id text,
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    discount numeric(5, 4)
)
```

For a particular product there shouldn't be overlapping promotions, i.e., the table shouldn't allow to have two rows for the same `product_id` with overlapping date ranges.

I don't know if it is possible, but I see this best coded as a constraint.

I've been looking around for solutions but I couldn't find anyone for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) using a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html):

```
alter table promotions
   add constraint no_overlapping_dates
   exclude using gist (product_id with =, 
                       daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]')  with &&);
```

The constraint is setup to include the end date in the range. If the end_date is the first date where the range is *not* valid, change the second parameter of the `daterange()` function to `'[)'`

You also need to [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the extension [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check it with a trigger and procedure
Something like;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_overlying_prom_dates() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
       IF (select end_date from promotions where product_id = NEW.product_id) >= NEW.start_date
       THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'cant overlay promotion dates';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER promotion_date_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON promotions
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_overlying_prom_dates();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I have changed the implementation to use the exclusion constraint using btree_gist as @a_horse_with_no_name explained.

Though, as far I've seen, btree_gist is only a trusted extensions from Postgres 13.0, so I leave this solution in case anyone that is trying to solve this problem cannot install untrusted extensions on its database.

---

Thank you all. I tried @dkc approach. The final code is this:

```
/*
  If we have two date ranges [x1, y1] & [x2, y2], they can overlap in 4 ways:

  1. ([)] -> x1 <= x2 && y1 >= x2
  2. [(]) -> x1 <= y2 && y1 >= y2
  3. [()] -> x1 >= x2 && y1 <= y2
  4. ([]) -> x1 <= x2 && y1 >= y2
*/
create or replace function check_overlying_prom_dates()
returns trigger
as $$
begin
if (
    -- case 1
    select bool_or(new.start_date <= start_date and new.end_date >= start_date)
    from promotions
    where product_id = new.product_id
    ) or (
    -- case 2
    select bool_or(new.start_date <= end_date and new.end_date >= end_date)
    from promotions
    where product_id = new.product_id
    ) or (
    -- case 3
    select bool_or(new.start_date >= start_date and new.end_date <= end_date)
    from promotions
    where product_id = new.product_id
    ) or (
    -- case 4
    select bool_or(new.start_date <= start_date and new.end_date >= end_date)
    from promotions
    where product_id = new.product_id
    )
then
    raise exception 'cant overlay promotion dates';
end if;
return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger promotion_date_trigger 
before insert or update on promotions
for each row execute procedure check_overlying_prom_dates();
```

Comment: The exclusion constraint will be way more efficient