# plpgsql function that checks if dates don't overlap

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, overlap

Hi I'm trying to write a function in plpgsql that inserts values into a table as long as the dates given when running the function are not in between already existing dates for the same room number (it's a hotel data base so I'm trying to check if the room a person is trying to book isn't already occupied in the time the person wants to book said room). The problem is the function is ignoring the statment and inserting values in even when the room is already booked.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_booking(room_id_ INTEGER,check_in_date_ DATE,check_out_date_ DATE ,comment_ TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE 
    arrival DATE;
    departure DATE;
    

BEGIN
    SELECT check_in_date INTO arrival FROM booking WHERE room_id = room_id_;
    SELECT check_out_date INTO departure FROM booking WHERE room_id = room_id_;



    IF (check_in_date_ BETWEEN arrival AND departure OR  check_out_date_ BETWEEN arrival AND departure) THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'This room is not available.'; 

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO booking(room_id ,booking_date,check_in_date,check_out_date,comment) VALUES (room_id_ ,CURRENT_DATE,check_in_date_,check_out_date_,comment_);
    END IF;


END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: 1) Choose either `MySQL` or `Postgres`. 2) Use [Range constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT).

Comment: no sure, but I suspect SELECT check_in_date INTO arrival FROM booking WHERE room_id = room_id_; is to be implemented as SELECT MAX(check_in_date) INTO arrival FROM booking WHERE room_id = room_id_;

Comment: No need for a trigger. This can be implemented with an exclusion constraint. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616099/postgres-date-overlapping-constraint) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388741/constraint-to-disallow-overlapping-dates)

Comment: This function can’t work when you have multiple concurrent inserts. The only safe option is a constraint

Comment: @Sergey. `Select MAX(check_in_date) ... `  is incorrect. The problem is reservations are by definition for future.  Consider: Client A reserves room 1 for  dates 2023-02-13 to 2023-02-17. Client B then reserves room 1 for  dates 2023-04-08 to 2320-04-11. Client C then reserves room 1 for dates 2302-02-14 - 2023-02-16. Using `MAX(check-in-date)` would allow the reservation for Client C  although the room is already reserved for those dates.